# How to start parallel releases in VSTS?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

We have 10 projects to release. It would be a time saver to start or create those releases in parallel. Right now we have to click and approve 10 pipelines. It takes around half an hour and 30 clicks.

Facts about Architecture

- every microservice has its own pipeline
- every pipeline has 3 artifacts

Comment: Do you have 10 different artifacts to publish ? If yes, why are you using 10 different release definitions ? Are they micro services or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Enable the Continuous Delivery trigger on each release definition.

Don't require approvals for lower environments within your deployment pipeline. Set the deployment condition for your lower environment to "After release is created".

That will immediately start deploying to the chosen environments after artifacts are published.

Then promote each service to the next stage in your pipeline as it's ready to go.

Since you stated they're microservices, they should be able to be deployed independently of one another with no degredation of service. Breaking changes should be extremely rare. If you find that you have to deploy many services in lock-step, you probably have an architecture problem, because the entire point of microservices is that they are independent of each other. At that point, you're no longer working with microservices, you're working with small, tightly coupled services.